# How to use OpenGL ES 3.2 on Android emulator?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to try the multiview extension for OpenGL ES 3.2 (see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OVR/OVR_multiview.txt).

My Smartphone does only support OpenGL ES 3.0 and I am unable to set GLES 3.2 on the Android Emulator Device Settings. This should work according to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html (search for OpenGL 3.2) and I have Android Studio 3.0.1 (which isn't preview version anymore...).

While the emulated device was running I was able to set unter Setting - Advanced a OpenGL ES API level to 'Renderer maximum (up to OpenGL ES 3.1) but I need 3.2 :/

Is that possible? I need OpenGL ES 3.2 with multiview extension to write a application for a possible employment at a VR/AR research laboratory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but if somebody reads this, there should be some answer.

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3 and I have used OpenGL ES 3.2 inside a native code (C++). You need to use the header

#include < gles3/gl32.h >

which can be found from the path:

```
/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/GLES3/gl32.h
```

This works if you have written a native library in your project. However, if you don't want to write a native library and want to stick to the java code, then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: saved me a day!!! first I use #include <GLES3/gl3.h> that can not reference "GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER", when I use your method, I can reference "GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER", great!